# Why does while not loop after grep?

Tags: perl, loops, filesystems

I have this piece of perl code:

```
open( FILENAME, "<", "some_valid_path");
my $needs_tags = 0;
if (!grep{/$open_tag/} <FILENAME>){
    $needs_tags = 1;
}
while ( <FILENAME> )
{
    warn "$_\n";
}
```

The problem is that after `grep`, `while` no longer runs, at all. But if I remove `grep`, `while` works.

Why is this behavior and how to fix?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes as it's not a straightforward, easy to find solution. I googled quite some time before posting

Comment: Your example isn't complete and runnable (you don't use strict and warnings, or define $open_tag). But regardless it's enough information in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grep` imposes *list [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context)*, in which [<>](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) reads the whole file and returns a list of lines.

So there is nothing left on the filehandle to run the `while`.

If that `grep` *is* supposed to go through the whole file, then after that [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) back to the beginning with `seek FILENAME, 0, 0` and then read again line by line.

---

As the whole file is being read at once, might as well store lines in an array and work with that

```
my @lines = <FILENAME>;
# chomp @lines;  # if needed

$needs_tags = 1 if not grep { /.../ } @lines;

for (@lines) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

You've consumed all the input data and exhausted the filehandle, so unless you rewind the file, you'll need to re-open it to get it back to the start so you can scan again.

You can reposition the read pointer with [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html):

```
seek(FILENAME, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

If you want to do this in one read pass you'll have to capture the input to an array first, then grep and loop again.

Comment: I'm upvoting because I'm sure you know what you're talking about, but for me the SEEK_SET threw an error, I needed to have the explicit `0` there, like the accepted answer did

Comment: Just working from the manual, didn't have time to test it, sorry about that. Those are from [`Fcntl`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Fcntl.html) and may have to be imported with `use`. The constants make your code more readable than some arbitrary zero value.